# Redmine incoming email fixed_version is not parsed correctly

Tags: parsing, email, version, redmine

Im running redmine 2.3.4 on ubuntu server.
My problem is that i can't set target version for issue when i open it through email.
My crontab line looks like this

```
*/1 * * * * rake -f /opt/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=imap.gmail.com port=993 username=rrr@rrr.rrr password=somepassword ssl=true tracker=Task priority=Normal project=inbox status=New allow_override=project,priority,tracker,status,fixed_version
```

email that i send looks like that

```
Project: ccc
Tracker: Release
fixed_version: test
status: WorksForMe
```

Project is set correctly.
Tracker is set correctly.
status is set correctly.
But fixed_version for some reason remains in issue description and not set properly ,target version remains empty.
Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mischa The Evil
www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/40127?r=40149#message-40149

> IIRC, the valid keywords are "Fixed version" and "Target version" or
>   its localized equivalents.